# How do I charge a 2100v 0.95uF capacitor?

Tags: capacitor, electricity, capacitor-charging

I'm trying to make a rail gun, and I am using 4 microwave capacitors for the extra kick but I don't know how to charge them. I would like to know how charging capacitors works and what I'll need to get to charge them.

Comment: You charge them with a voltage source, you do need to have some knowledge of circuit theory before asking questions on this site. A project like this is very dangerous especially when you don't understand what is going on.

Comment: A stick of dynamite is 1,000,000 joules. You will have 16 joules stored. Can you protect yourself?

Comment: What is it with so many noobs posting on charging capacitor to  2000V 4000V etc .................

Comment: @MITURAJ Probably there is a youtube video popular about rail guns...

Comment: Read it it's rights. Then cart it off for interrogation.

Comment: Given your level of knowledge, these are probably not parts you can safely work with. Step back and learn some more before you proceed.

Comment: Why do you want to make a rail gun?! What are your intentions?! I'm not ready for world war 3 !!

Comment: I'm a professional EE and I would think twice about doing something like this. High voltage at high current is totally unforgiving. There is no such thing as a "simple mistake". You will get an explosion than can destroy equipment and flesh equally well. You need serious protective equipment

Comment: Well, i wanted to make a railgun because why not. First, I made a jacobs ladder then to a Tesla coil, why because i always wanted to make one, now i want to make a railgun. Now, what should i use Voltage/amps wise to charge these capacitors? And yes im sure i can protect myself. @Dick Bruere, what would you suggest i use for capacitors then?

Answer (score 7):

**WARNING: A mistake with a high-voltage charged capacitor can lead to death, or a missing finger!!! Do NOT try this until you have a high-voltage probe rated 40 KV (Tektronix)** The probe divides by 1,000 and cost a few hundred dolars.

You will need a step-up transformer that puts out 1,200 VAC maximum. The peak DC voltage will be 1,700 volts. Do NOT attempt to charge the capacitor anywhere near its maximum rating.

You will have to buy 2 transformers with 120/240 primaries and 600 VAC secondaries. Put the secondaries in series to get 1,200 VAC.

You must buy rectifiers rated 3 times the DC voltage on the capacitor, because the capacitor will have +1700 volts on it when the AC swing back in the negative direction, putting about 2,400 volts potential on this rectifier. So it needs to be rated about 5 KV and several amps. This gives you about a 50% or so safety margin with the rectifiers.

The way we did this at work was put many 6A10 diodes in series. Five of them in series with 3 each 120 K 1/2 W (360 K) bleed resistors across each diode will give you a 5 KV 6 AMP rating. The inrush current into an empty capacitor means you must use diodes that can tolerate such currents for a brief time.

You must buy high voltage bleed resistors of 1 M or so rated 20 KV from Caddock. Digikey carries them. About $50 USD to $75 USD each. Place them across the capacitor so it will always self-discharge if not used. Do NOT short it out with a screw driver. It will go **BANG** loud enough to make you deaf.

I don't think this will make much of a rail gun, which needs sustained power for several milliseconds. You may need a 100 of these capacitors in parallel. Something I do not want to think about.